# Using tippy.js with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

For a while I've been using the react-tippy package, but it hasn't been updated in a long time and it has many bugs.

Recently [@atomiks](https://github.com/atomiks) published a react wrapper for his tippy.js library.

I've used succesfully until I need to use it together with React-Router or Redux.

**I've created a sandbox that replicates the issue ➡ https://codesandbox.io/s/9yr3rmrkny**

Ideally somebody is able to figure out how to tweak the tippy.js wrapper to render the tippyInstance with Context (for both redux and react-router)

Comment: Do you have a question? Or is it _Invariant Violation_ because the output is hinting at `You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

Comment: [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Tippy has upgraded to v3 and they now have a really good support for react.

https://github.com/atomiks/tippy.js-react

This issue I posted is no longer an issue with the newer version and React Component

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the internals of how Tippy works, I.E. manipulating the DOM directly rather than going through the React provided virtual-dom. Due to this fact, it would be suggested to not use Tippy with React at all because it breaks the same rules as using jQuery with React. [see here](https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-mix-jquery-and-react-cit77t20z02j5fq536wlyiwtk)

Sadly, updating the wrapper wouldn't help anything as the DOM manipulation is happening within the Tippy source code, rather than the react wrapper.

What I ended up doing was rebuilding the Tippy functionality I needed in React.
There are also other tooltip libraries that are geared better for React that could be looked into.

I realize this isn't the most helpful answer, but wanted to share what I ran into, also thanks for asking this because it helped figure out what was causing my bug.

**EDIT**

as pointed out in previous answer, and comment. This is an issue with old version of tippy (v<3.0).

Comment: Thanks! I just posted the answer since the newer version is great and solves all the problems. Maybe it helps you as well.